# How do I prevent Sublime Text 3 from auto-indenting a line as a one off

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I'm editing HTML or CSS in Sublime Text 3 the lines auto-indent when I hit the [ENTER] key, which generally is very useful.

On occasion I find myself wanting to paste a line of markup which is already indented, and this results in double indentation.

Is there some other key combination along with the [ENTER] key that prevents the next line from auto-indenting and instead returns the curson to the very beginning of the line?  Please note I don't want to turn off auto-indent on a global basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in Windows that CTRL + SHIFT + V (rather than just CTRL + V) does a "paste and indent" whereby the indentation is corrected as necessary.

It's also possible to switch the default paste for paste as indent as per these instructions: https://gist.github.com/twosixcode/1988097

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in various steps, using various keybindings, so you can simply **record a macro and do it in one simple custom keybinding** (tools > record macro).

Steps:

1. Press *[Enter]* to move to a new line.
2. Press *[shift+home]* to select until the beginning of line (spaces or tabs used to indent).
3. Press *[backspace]* to remove the selected indentation charaters
4. You're done. Stop recording and save the macro, then use a custom keybinding to do it in a single step.

Comment: Thanks, this will come in useful for the future but I answered my own question as above