# How to delete everything to the right of selected text in Sublime Text 3 ?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am not sure if this possible. I am just checking to see if it is.

Is there a way to delete everything to the right of whatever I select in Sublime Text ?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896916/how-do-i-prevent-sublime-text-3-from-auto-indenting-a-line-as-a-one-off/28899637#28899637) i gave to another question. You might find it helpful for your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select "//" using Command + D adding a cursor to each element found (like you did) you can use Command + Shift + Arrow Right to select the text between the cursor and the end of the line then you can delete the selected text.

Answer (score 2):

As Mauricio stated, after using  + D to add multiple cursors,  + K (twice) should do it. This will delete anything to the right of the cursor.  To delete to the left of the cursor, select  + K, followed by  + .